# Hosting website when port 80 is taken?

Tags: networking, web-server

A few months ago, we purchased an R-HUB unit to replace WebEx for remote support. The device operates through port 80, which doesn't appear to be configurable. I know in IIS, you can specify a port besides port 80, but the problem is in the port forwarding.

On our router, we have to map an incoming port to the forward port which then directs traffic to the node (webserver). However, the incoming port for both the webserver and the R-HUB is 80 - and the server seems to be getting confused as I can only get to the R-HUB, not the website.

How can I expose both devices? Host headers? DNS config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the R-HUB and the IIS (?) server in question on the same box?  I'm assuming so.  Anyway, you could set up two different IPs on that box and bind the services only to certain IP addresses.  IIS binds to all by default but you can tell it not to, see http://devlicio.us/blogs/billy_mccafferty/archive/2008/09/02/prevent-iis-from-binding-to-all-assigned-ip-addresses.aspx.

Actually, the R-HUB is a device isn't it?  Why is it conflicting at all?  Just give it a different external IP than your Web server and different DNS names (www.whoever.com, conference.whoever.com).

Comment: The R-HUB is a separate device, but we only have one external IP. I was trying to serve both with one IP address.

Comment: You won't be able to serve two things on the same IP and same port.  Well... Okay, you could.  The main thing is that all that traffic has to go to one place, and that one place needs to figure out what to do with it.  What you'd have to do is to have the traffic go to the Web server and then set up a virtual host there to proxy through to the R-HUB.  Or optionally use a proxy or load balancing layer (ha-proxy for example) to do content based routing for you.  But unless your router does layer 7 inspection, you can't send same IP/same port traffic 2 different places.

Comment: This is easy on ISA/TMG btw (just trying to do the "this is easy on apache" quote thingie :)